# Change the way the Visual Studio debugger displays char variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a program in which I'm using the `unsigned char` type to represent integers, but when inspecting the variables in the debugger with Visual Studio 2005, it's showing me the ASCII character representations, whereas I would like to see the decimal representation. Does anyone know of a way to change the way it displays the data?

Comment: Using `char` to represent an integer is usually not what you want, since its signedness is unspecified.  `signed char` or `unsigned char` would be preferable.  I think the debugger will print the value of either of those types in integer form.

Comment: I am in fact using `unsigned char`, I just neglected to say so. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Good.  :-)  Unfortunately, I don't know whether there is a solution to your question, aside from casting, as suggested by John Dibling.  The Visual Studio 11 Beta debugger shows both the numeric value (in decimal or hexadecimal, depending on your settings) and the character interpretation of that value.  This may have been a feature that was added after Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a variable `foo` declared as `uint32_t`, and you want to display `foo` as if it were actually a `float`.  In the watch window, you can enter the expression:

`*(float*)&foo`

...and it will display `foo` cast as a `float`.

Comment: In this case, `(int)foo` would probably suffice, since `char` and friends are all integer types.

Comment: @John Thanks, that's useful to know. But I'm inspecting variables by using the expanders (+) from higher-level data structures. For example, I have an object which contains three lists, each of which contain a couple of hundred objects which themselves contain a few `unsigned char`s. I'd like to be able to see the entire list at a glance as integers rather than characters.